# Function Reuse Across Routes in Express/Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a web app with Node.js and Express. I have two route files that both need the same function. I was wondering where I should define this function. Should it go in a different folder (helpers or utils or something?) or a different file in my routes folder. My current folder structure is quite similar to https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Mybrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the same function, it is convenient that you define it in a single file, and import it in your routes. The place where to save it is not important, it depends on the order of your project. by example:

```
folder libs
--tokenValidator.js

folder routes
--folder create
----createCustomers.js
--folder read
----readCustomers.js
```

tokenValidator.js contains:

```
module.exports = {
        
    ensureToken (req, res, next) {

       const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
       //console.log(bearerHeader);

       if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
           const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' '); //separar bearer del token por espacios
           const bearerToken = bearer[1]; //seleccionar el token
           req.token = bearerToken; //comparar el token del servidor con el recibido
           //console.log('token Validator fine')
           next();
       } else {
           res.sendStatus(403);
           //console.log('Fail in token Validator')
       }         
   }
};
```

createCustomers.js containts

```
const { ensureToken } = require('../../libs/tokenValidator.js');

router.post('/dataClient', ensureToken,  (req, res)=>{

    jwt.verify(req.token, 'token_key', async (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
            //console.log('token error')
        } else {
            res.send('token ok')
        }
    })
    
});
```

readCustomers.js containts

```
const { ensureToken } = require('../../libs/tokenValidator.js');

router.post('/dataClient', ensureToken,  (req, res)=>{

    jwt.verify(req.token, 'token_key', async (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
            //console.log('token error')
        } else {
            res.send('token ok')
        }
    })
    
});
```